# AutoLayout - Not able to set UIImage Width as desired

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, xcode-storyboard

Following are the autolayout constraints I have added:

[image]

And the final result is as follows:

[image]

UIImage Content mode : Aspect Fit.

Label content hugging priority vertical : 253 (rest all are default for both imageview and label)

I have added a placeholder image until the image is actually downloaded. I have used 2 prototype cells in tableView - One with label. Another with Image and Label.

What I want to achieve is set the width of UIImage to 50% of screen size and let the height be calculated automatically based on aspect ratio.

cell.layoutSubviews also didnt help

Any help is really appreciated. Would like to achive this via storyboard itself if thats possible.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Set Image View's width constraint to 50% width of the Content View instead of 70% of the Title Label.

Comment: @EugeneDudnyk Done as advised. No luck still. Also updated the screenshot to reflect the changes

Answer (score 0):

Set the width to 50% of the screen width. Programmtically it is written as `imageView.frame.width = UIScreen.main.bounds.width / 2` I'm not sure how that would be done in storyboard. And set your desired aspect ratio constraint in the storyboard. The only constraints for the image should be its position in the cell, the aspect ratio, and the width. No height constraints.

Comment: Aspect ratio of width to height of imageView? I want the height to be calculated automatically based on the width